# How do I add an app to a workspace through the Watson Workspace API?

Tags: ibm-watson

I know how to add an app manually to a workspace using the Watson Workspace GUI, but now I need to automate this.

Is there a way to connect an app to a specific workspace using the API?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is an API to achieve this. As far as I am aware of there’s a webhook to see if there are any changes happening in a space like users added or removed.

You can find the GraphQL API and other details [here](https://developer.watsonwork.ibm.com/docs/apps/prepare-your-app-to-run)